# Is there a community for learning Sindarin?

Tags: languages, elves, tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

For years now I try to engage myself in how to **learn Quenya or Sindarin**. I started with [two printed](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/qcourse.htm) [excellent courses](http://www.scribd.com/doc/6710772/Quenya-Elvish-Language-Course-Tolkien), but couldn't motivate myself to keep at it — it is difficult when you are only learning by yourself.

Therefore: Is there any **online community** where one could practice, keep motivating each other and collectively learn Sindarin? An **offline community** would be even better, but that would have to be in *Northrhine-Westphalia, Germany,* then for my purposes.

I know about the [Mythgard Institute](http://www.mythgard.org/), but they don't offer courses, yet. Real classes with a course schedule and fellow students would be perfect.

Comment: Is this a good question?  I answered it flippantly with 3 places to look on the first page of google.  Have you looked at all of the links on the first two pages there? It looks to me like there is a huge amount of these kinds of sites and communities.  This is looks easy to answer with a trivial search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is. It's not as well organized as the Klingon community is, but it's present none the less.

Mostly, by participation in the forums associated with the journals, in the appropriate mailing lists.

The one I can find to hand, without much effort: http://groups.yahoo.com/group/elfling/